# Unable to Properly Consume Data from $resource in Angular

Tags: ajax, angularjs, parse-platform

I'm building a prototype app using Parse.com as a temporary backend.

This is how Parse structures its returned data when a request is made.

```
    {
      "results": [
        {
          "playerName": "Jang Min Chul",
          "updatedAt": "2011-08-19T02:24:17.787Z",
          "cheatMode": false,
          "createdAt": "2011-08-19T02:24:17.787Z",
          "objectId": "A22v5zRAgd",
          "score": 80075
        },
        {
          "playerName": "Sean Plott",
          "updatedAt": "2011-08-21T18:02:52.248Z",
          "cheatMode": false,
          "createdAt": "2011-08-20T02:06:57.931Z",
          "objectId": "Ed1nuqPvcm",
          "score": 73453
        }
      ]
    }
```

I have a factory that looks like this

```
app.factory('eventFactory', ['$resource', function($resource){
            return $resource('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Events', {},
                {   'get':    {method:'GET'},
                    'save':   {method:'POST'},
                    'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:false},
                    'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
                    'delete': {method:'DELETE'}
                });

            }
        ]);
```

My controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('currentTradeshowsController', function($scope, eventFactory){



        var testSave = eventFactory.get();
                    console.log(testSave);

        console.log(testSave.results);

    });
```

the first console.log for 'testSave' looks like this :

[image: Imgur]

Where as testSave.results returns undefined.

I would think that I would be able to access all the objects this way no?

What am I missing here?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Your .get() returns a promise object. To get the actual data you have to pass in a callback like .get(function(response) { console.log(response);}); or use.then(function()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `$resource` does a very nice job of abstracting, the fact remains that since it works via HTTP calls it runs asynchronously and the code has to be written to handle that semantically.  [The documentation expresses this.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

```
var testSave = eventFactory.get().success(function () {
    console.log(testSave);
});
```

Unfortunately the Angular docs do not make it clear, but I think the above will work.  Possible alternatives are:

```
.get(function () {
.get({}, function () {
.get().then(function () {
.get().$promise.then(function () {
```

Find one that works and works best for you.  The idea is that the success callback and anything that relies on a successful request need to be in this function.